# getting number of rows in sql result in php

Tags: php, sql

Is there a way to write php code to give you the amount of rows in a sql query (and print the number on the screen) without having to make an actual loop through each row and adding up the numbers?

Comment: Yes, it is. Which library are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MySQL its mysql_num_rows:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Comment: mysql_num_rows requires transferring the data set from MySQL to the calling code.  In other words, doing a SELECT and then doing mysql_num_rows is usually not the best approach unless you're planning on actually using the result set and don't just want a row count.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for COUNT?

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as number_users FROM users
```

Then it's treated like a normal resource where you can pull out the row and number_users column.

Edit:  Your question a is a bit oddly worded.  It also sounds like you might be looking for SUM() and GROUP BY.  Or maybe COUNT() and GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

multiple ways:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) `tot` FROM table
```

(attention, not `COUNT(field)`, as if `field` is NULL the row won't be counted)

of, if you have already queried the database and you want to know all the rows that you have pulled, let's say inside an array, you could do a

```
count($array)
```

if you haven't looped the values but planning on it, you could execute a `mysql_num_rows`

and finally, if you executed a `SELECT` with `LIMIT` in it, you could run add `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` to the select and then use the [FOUND_ROWS()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM table WHERE field="value" LIMIT 0,100; /* grab first 100 rows WHERE field="value" */
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();  /* return the total number of rows WHERE field="value" */
```